# meshed objects are changing color

Tags: mesh

We are attempting to join spheres and a cube and text together for a school project but when we try to join them they all turn the same color.  What can we do to keep that from happening?

Comment: How are you joining them?

Comment: Welcome to Blender SE. When joining two different meshes in Object Mode (CNTL/CMD-J), the mesh doesn't know how to remap material qualities to this new mesh. Tab into Edit mode. In the Materials panel, click "+" to add a second material for your mesh, and select the material that vanished. Then, select each face that should have the second material, and click the 'Assign' button under the Materials list..